# storing decimal into pgtype numeric

Tags: postgresql, go, decimal, pgx

I was working with `pgtype.NumRange`. The lower and upper bounds are typed `pgtype.Numeric`. pgtype.Numeric has the following fields

```
type Numeric struct {
    Int              *big.Int
    Exp              int32
    Status           Status
    NaN              bool
    InfinityModifier InfinityModifier
}
```

I guess I'm suppose to able to represent any number using the duo of the `Int` and `Exp` fields, but I don't know how to, as `big.Int` and `int32' are integer types.

From [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-range.html), I can see that `numrange` can take decimal values in any of lower and upper bounds and data type numeric is a superset of decimal type. So I know I should be able to use decimals, but
how can I go about this?

Comment: If you're asking how to initialize an instance of `pgtype.Numeric` then you need not look any further than the _test.go file for the type: https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/numeric_test.go

Comment: Judging from the implementation something like this should work: `x := new(pgtype.Numeric); err := x.Set("3.145")`.

Comment: @Peter, yeah that works. Thanks. Add your comment as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: Can someone tell me what the reverse of this is? I've been banging my head against it all day.

I have a bunch of pgtype.Numeric results and I want the float out, but buggered if I can work it out.